# Android, SQLite, ошибка

Tags: android-sdk, android

Не могу понять что не так. После запуска блока кода вылетает приложение, вот код и метод из блока:

```
    //Блок кода
    if (dictionaries.length>0) {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + Integer.toString(dictionaries.length));
        for (int j=0; j<dictionaries.length; j++) 
            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "старт!"); 
            createTable(dictionaries[i]);
    }



    //Метод
    private void createTable(String table) {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "createTable: запуск");

        DBHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DBHelper(this, table);
        mDatabaseHelper.close();

        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "createTable: завершение");
    }
```

Когда выполнение доходит до этого блока, в лог высвечивается сообщение "старт!" и приложение вылетает ("приложение остановлено"). Как ни странно, сообщения "createTable: запуск" - нет!

Если нужно, вот код базы данных:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    String name;
    final String TAG = "APP";
    final String MSG = "БАЗА ДАННЫХ: ";

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, 1);
    }

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name) { 
        super(context, name, null, 1);

        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "запуск с значением " + name);

        this.name = name;

        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "запуск завершен");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "создание таблицы " + name);

        if (name.equals("dictionaries")) {
            db.execSQL("create table "
                    + name + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + "dictionary"
                    + " String);");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "создание таблицы 1"); 
            db.execSQL("create table "
                    + name + "_verb" + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + "last"
                    + " String, " + "currently" + " String, " + "next"
                    + " String, " + "translate + String);");
            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "создание таблицы 2"); 
            db.execSQL("create table "
                    + name + "_noun" + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + "word"
                    + " String, " + "translate" + " String);");
            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "создание таблицы 3"); 
            db.execSQL("create table "
                    + name + "_phrase" + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + "phrase"
                    + " String, " + "translate" + " String);");
        }

        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "создание завершено");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {      
    }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Толи вы криво выложили фрагменты кода, толи вы не понимаете что вы делаете. Во первых ваш цикл в "блоке кода" выводит только ```Log.i(TAG, MSG + "старт!"); ```.  Во вторых, откуда взялась переменная ```i``` в "блоке кода"? Возможно вы ее где то раньше объявили, поэтому и скомпилировалось без ошибок, но ее значение больше чем количество элементов в массиве. Ну и в третьих, если у вас возникает какая либо ошибка, то прикладывайте лог этой ошибки, а то получается гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Ух е... Накосячил я конкретно... Называется писал, когда уже засыпал. Днем буду дома - отредактирую. Спасибо что указали на ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есть определённые правила оформления кода которым вы здесь явно не следуете - в for-e, по коду из листинга крутиться только лог, к тому же переменные скорее всего перепутали

```
   if (dictionaries.length > 0) {
    Log.i(TAG, MSG + Integer.toString(dictionaries.length));
       for (int j = 0; j < dictionaries.length; j++) {
         Log.i(TAG, MSG + "старт!"); 
         createTable(dictionaries[j]);
       }
    }
```